# manifest file used by Youtube for DASH

Tags: video, youtube, video-streaming

Streaming media files over Youtube uses Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (DASH). Client side receives a manifest file, from which it chooses what type of video quality will it receive, depending on the throughput the client has.

I ran some youtube video, opened Network tab to see the manifest file  that determines video quality(to see the code), but I don't know which file performs this quest. Do you know which file serves as the manifest regarding Youtube videos?

Comment: IIRC its a variation on a `.m3u` file.   I think they added another letter to the extension, but I forget at the moment

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Web services like Facebook, Twitter and YouTube are off topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [WebApps.SE].